# Is there a VS Code extension that provides a special editor for package.json?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, editor, vscode-extensions

Even for my small VS Code extension, the `package.json` is becoming pretty large and unwieldy. Is there a VS Code extension that provides a better editor for package.json? I have found [Json Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nickdemayo.vscode-json-editor), but I am looking for an editor that knows about the elements of a VS Code extension manifest, e.g. valid fields, contribution points, when clauses and icons. Also, an icon picker would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [better-package-json](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ldd-vs-code.better-package-json) for handling dependency versions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. At the moment, I'm not concerned with dependencies yet. May be later, should I ever get to maintaining my extension instead of developing it.